# Should I repeat on an article twice after "or"?

Tags: articles

Should I repeat an article after "or"?

For example:

> "It is a specific word that refers to **a** pronoun or (**a**) noun."

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. ...to a pronoun or noun.
2. ...to a pronoun or to a noun.
3. ...to a pronoun or a noun.

There is nothing grammatically wrong with any of them, so the choice rests on style and comprehensibility. The sentence is so short and so simple that I don't see any risk of misunderstanding or confusion.

For my money, I would go for option 2, because I think it sounds better, but that is purely a matter of taste.